# Can we pass a string( "emp id") as path variable to the controller in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, path-variables

I am writing an controller for one of spring based applications. I was extensively using path variable but I have few scenarios where I have stringswhich has spaces for example "bike racing" and I also have &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for doing that you need to define a regular expression on your request mapping, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/home/{test:[a-zA-Z &+-]*}")
public ModelAndView getTest(@PathVariable("test") String test) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("/test/teste");
    model.addObject("label_title", test);

    return model;
}
```

And then you will have your strings correctly:
[image: with space] [image: with &]

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.